# Forensic DVD-R data

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning, forensics

Forensically speaking, is there a way to read metadata, user profile, computer, or burning info on a DVD-R? I need to discover more about who made an illegal copy of a movie... Is this something better done on a Mac or PC, or do I need special software?

Comment: From the way the question was written, it seems you were sold a pirated copy and want to trace it...

Comment: Honestly, I'm trying to trace a homemade porn DVD.  Need to know who burned it if possible, or what little bytes of info might be left behind. :)

Comment: @AngelHills Did you see someone you know? :P

Comment: [Possibly according to this](http://superuser.com/questions/80056/is-it-possible-to-confirm-cd-was-burned-on-a-particular-machine)

Answer (score 2):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), a free disk burning program, can give you a lot of information on the DVD itself.

However, usually *no identifying informaton is stored* when a a disc is burned beside file modification times.